# jQuery resize stops functioning, throws error - TypeError: this.listeners is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, glidejs

The goal is to disable or enable slider functionality based on browser width.

My code works perfectly the first couple times the window is resized from big to small/small to big, but then it stops disabling the slider when the window is >= 1200 and the console says "TypeError: this.listeners is undefined" in relation to glide.destroy

I've spent hours googling these errors and still can't figure it out. I'm completely new to jQuery and having a really hard time with this one.

```
var id;

var isMounted = false;

var glide = new Glide("#intro", {
  type: "carousel",
  gap: "12",
  perView: 5,
  focusAt: "center",
  breakpoints: {
    800: {
      perView: 2
    },
    480: {
      perView: 1
    }
  }
});

if (jQuery(window).width() < 1200) {
  glide.mount();

  isMounted = true;
}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(id);

  id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing() {
  if (isMounted === true) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() >= 1200) {
      glide.destroy();

      isMounted = false;
      console.log("destroy false");
    }
  }

  if (isMounted === false) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 1200) {
      glide.mount();

      isMounted = true;
    }
    console.log("mount true");
  }
}
```

Looking at my browser console, it appears that at some point `glide.mount()` starts being run immediately after `glide.destroy` and I can't figure out why. Here's what I'm seeing (site name redacted for privacy reasons):

> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js:2:552
>
> mount true glide-custom-test-03.js:44:34
>
> Will-change memory consumption is too high. Budget limit is the document surface area multiplied by 3 (289296 px). Occurrences of will-change over the budget will be ignored.
>
> destroy false glide-custom-test-03.js:38:36
>
> mount true glide-custom-test-03.js:44:34
>
> TypeError: this.listeners is undefinedglide.min.js:6:5987
>
> value -/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> unbind -/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> Resize -/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> value -/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> forEach self-hosted:262
>
> value -/wp-content/themes/apt2c/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> value -/wp-content/themes/apt2c/js/slider/glide/dist/glide.min.js?ver=1.1:6
>
> doneResizing -/wp-content/themes/apt2c/js/slider/glide/custom/glide-custom-test-03.js?ver=1.1:37

Comment: One obvious this is change `if (isMounted === false) {` to `else if (isMounted === false) {`. Because right above that you are changing isMounted to be false so this will always be called.

Comment: @imvain2 the `isMounted` is set as a default and is conditionally modified to `true` if window size is less than 1200 pixels. There is a conflict if `isModified` is `true` when doneResizing() is run. It will be set to `false` and the next condition test will be met.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to review the logic of your tests. Maybe even move them to their own functions. Basically, you're constantly checking if the window size has exceeded a specific threshold. In this case, a width of 1200.

```
function checkWindow(n){
  return jQuery(window).width() < n;
}

var glide = new Glide("#intro", {
  type: "carousel",
  gap: "12",
  perView: 5,
  focusAt: "center",
  breakpoints: {
    800: {
      perView: 2
    },
    480: {
      perView: 1
    }
  }
});

var intro = jQuery("#intro").data("mounted", false);

if (checkWindow(1200)) {
  glide.mount();
  intro.data("mounted", true);
  console.log("Init, Glide: mount, Mounted: true");
}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(id);

  id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});

function doneResizing() {
  if (intro.data("mounted") && checkWindow(1200) === false) {
    glide.destroy();
    intro.data("mounted", false);  
    console.log("Resize, Glide: destroy, Mounted: false");
  } else if (intro.data("mounted") === false && checkWindow(1200)) {
    glide.mount();
    intro.data("mounted", true);  
    console.log("Resize, Glide: mount, Mounted: true");
  }
}
```

I moved the storage of the mount to the data attribute of the element. This way if you have more than 1, you can more easily check the status.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm getting the same 'TypeError: this.listeners is undefined' error and issues as before. Going to keep poking at it and see what I can come up with.